# Javascript functions not working in an jsp file

Tags: javascript, html, jsp

I have a jsp file that is not running my javascript functions. It worked when it was in an html file. Here is the html and javascript used to create this. The javascript switches the visibility of parts of a form when radio buttons are clicked.

```
<script language="Javascript">
     //How many Questions
     function CTDefault(){
       document.getElementById("CTDefault").style.visibility="visible";
       document.getElementById("CTManual").style.visibility="hidden";
       document.getElementById("CTFile").style.visibility="hidden";
     }
     //Manual
     function CTManual(){
        document.getElementById("CTDefault").style.visibility="hidden";
        document.getElementById("CTManual").style.visibility="visible";
        document.getElementById("CTFile").style.visibility="hidden";  
     }
     //Load Data from Form
     function CTFile(){
        document.getElementById("CTDefault").style.visibility="hidden";
        document.getElementById("CTManual").style.visibility="hidden";
        document.getElementById("CTFile").style.visibility="visible";   
     }
</script>
<!--Buttons-->
<div id="enterDataToggle" class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons" >
<!--Default-->
<label class="btn btn-default active" id="checkin-label">
     <input type="radio" onClick="CTDefault()" checked> Default
</label>

<!--Input Data Manually-->
<label class="btn btn-default active" id="checkin-label">
     <input type="radio" checked onClick="CTManual()">
     Input Data Manually
</label>

<!--Load Data from File-->
<label class="btn btn-default active" id="checkin-label"
    <input type="radio" value="checking" onClick="CTFile()">
                    Load Data from File
</label>

</div>

<!-- CT Input Data Default--> 
<div style= "visibility:hidden; position:absolute" id="CTDefault">
    <h4>Default-If you don't have this data, we have data for you. You do not have to do anything else. If you have data please click input data manually or load data from file.</h4>
</div>

<!--CT Manually-->
<div style=" position:absolute" id="CTManual">
    <table class="table table-bordered table-striped">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Mean</th>
                <th>Standard Deviation</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <th>
                    <input name="CTMean" type="text" style="width:100%" required>
                </th>
                <th>
                    <input name="CTStd" type="text" style="width:100%" required>
                </th>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Any help is appreciated! :)

Comment: you can use trace mode(F12) to check what sort of problem do you have

Comment: There are no errors one the webpage, just some warnings that have to do with my css file. Can you elaborate more on how to use trace mode?

Comment: It turn out the three lines that look like this:<label class="btn btn-default active" id="checkin-label"> should not have the last ">". i.e. they should look like this - <label class="btn btn-default active" id="checkin-label"   After I made that change everything worked.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe if you declare your script after the html tags:

```
<!--Buttons-->
<div id="enterDataToggle" class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons" >
<!--Default-->
<label class="btn btn-default active" id="checkin-label">
     <input type="radio" name="option" onClick="CTDefault()" checked> Default
</label>

<!--Input Data Manually-->
<label class="btn btn-default active" id="checkin-label">
     <input type="radio" name="option" checked onClick="CTManual()">
     Input Data Manually
</label>

<!--Load Data from File-->
<label class="btn btn-default active" id="checkin-label">
    <input type="radio" name="option" value="checking" onClick="CTFile()">
                    Load Data from File
</label>

</div>

<!-- CT Input Data Default--> 
<div style= "visibility:hidden; position:absolute" id="CTDefault">
    <h4>Default-If you don't have this data, we have data for you. You do not have to do anything else. If you have data please click input data manually or load data from file.</h4>
</div>

<!-- CT Input Data Default--> 
<div style= "visibility:hidden; position:absolute" id="CTFile">
    <h4>CTFile.</h4>
</div>

<!--CT Manually-->
<div style=" position:absolute" id="CTManual">
    <table class="table table-bordered table-striped">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Mean</th>
                <th>Standard Deviation</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <th>
                    <input name="CTMean" type="text" style="width:100%" required>
                </th>
                <th>
                    <input name="CTStd" type="text" style="width:100%" required>
                </th>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
<script language="Javascript">
     //How many Questions
     function CTDefault(){
       document.getElementById("CTDefault").style.visibility="visible";
       document.getElementById("CTManual").style.visibility="hidden";
       document.getElementById("CTFile").style.visibility="hidden";
     }
     //Manual
     function CTManual(){
        document.getElementById("CTDefault").style.visibility="hidden";
        document.getElementById("CTManual").style.visibility="visible";
        document.getElementById("CTFile").style.visibility="hidden";  
     }
     //Load Data from Form
     function CTFile(){
        document.getElementById("CTDefault").style.visibility="hidden";
        document.getElementById("CTManual").style.visibility="hidden";
        document.getElementById("CTFile").style.visibility="visible";   
     }
</script>
```

Your plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/m0f9XPdA4t85mYJpizl4?p=preview

PS:

- one label tag wasn't closed properly
- element with id CTFile didn't exists in your example
- you should name your radio buttons with a unique name